# Floating box I can't get rid of!

Tags: helper, footer, facebook

I'm looking to get rid of the bottom right empty box on the footer of my site http://caliudeflandes.com/ - There used to be a FB box, we deleted it but the box stayed and can't get rid. Any tips? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**To remove it from your template files**

Go to

> /app/design/frontend/default/[your theme]/template/page/html/footer.phtml

Delete or comment out

```
<div class="span3"> 
    <div class="facebook">
    <div class="footer-static-title">
    .....
    </div>
</div>
```

**To hide it using css**

```
.mt-footer-static-container-bottom div.span3{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! However I cannot see that configuration ;|

Comment: What configuration?

Comment: <div class="span3"> 
    <div class="facebook">
    <div class="footer-static-title">
    .....
    </div>
</div> 

this